# OnActivityResult not call inside fragment but the Main Activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, callback

I am working on a fragment that call camera.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

The problem is , if I overwrite the onActivityResult inside the fragment, it does not call,

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("test","result frag");

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

but only call the `onActivityResult` in Main Activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   Log.d("test","main");
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

After some findings, there is some solution by calling the fragment method inside the Main Activity 's `onActivityResult` function. But how can I fix it with other approach? Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [onActivityResult not being called in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: Thanks for remind, the problem is I already use startActivityForResult(intent,111) in fragment instead of getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,111) , but still can not call.

Comment: Check the other answers too. For some reason there are 11 answers with  at least one upvote.

Comment: yes I found in that post almost all use fragment.startActivityForResult apporach, I would like to find any other workaround. Sorry for that if it duplicate from others.

Comment: You need to check the whole post. There are simple things like the activity's launch mode and history and such... :)

Comment: Important --> Fragment is a child of an Activity,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` in your fragment.

Comment: And should he do that? It doesn't even make sense